# Регулярное выражение для извлечения имён пользователей

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Есть журнал, в котором надо разобрать ники персонажей. Вот отрывок HTML разметки.
Надо составить регулярку, которая будет парсить ники, которые помечены жирным курсивным текстом. Даже не знаю за что можно зацепиться в данной ситуации.

```
<font class='B9'>
  <font class='B1'>
    <IMG src=http://img.combats.ru/i/align25.gif width=12 height=15>
    <IMG src=http://img.combats.ru/i/klan/MadSquirrels.gif width=24 height=15>
    Manchester Utd
  </font>
</font> [1065/3497],
<font class='B9'>
  <font class='B1'>
    <IMG src=http://img.combats.ru/i/align25.gif width=12 height=15>
    <IMG src=http://img.combats.ru/i/klan/KnightsOfTheBalance.gif width=24 height=15>
    Frans
  </font>
</font> [50/3963]
<SPAN style='color: red; font-weight: bold; '>против</SPAN>
<font class='B9'>
  <font class='B2'>
    <IMG src=http://img.combats.ru/i/align14.gif width=12 height=15>
    <IMG src=http://img.combats.ru/i/klan/TerriblePower.gif width=24 height=15>
    рвот
  </font>
</font> [1519/4144]<HR>
```

Comment: http://habrahabr.ru/post/110112/ Такие вещи регулярками не делаются.

Comment: О, в очередной раз парсим HTML регулярками.

Запомните раз и навсегда: регулярки — неподходящее средство для разбора HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/([^>]+)<\/font><\/font>/g
```

http://regex101.com/r/vY9vR9

Comment: Спасибо большое,как всегда выручаете)) Осталось разобраться в самой регулярке

Comment: я уже писал вам, но еще раз напомню, воспользуйтесь какой-нибудь библиотекой для работы с DOM, это сильно упростит вам жизнь, тем более если есть проблемы с составлением регулярных выражений.

Посмотрите, на сколько это просто http://habrahabr.ru/post/176635/

И еще совет: если вы получили удовлетворяющий ответ на свой вопрос, помечайте его как "верный" (галочка слева от ответа)

Comment: Спасибо попробую! Дело не в том что я ищу легкие,готовые решения.С одной стороны самому хочется научиться хорошо владеть регулярками,потихоньку их осваиваю.С другой стороны если такие проблемы глупо решать регулярками,то тогда уже другое дело)

Comment: Кстати небольшой вопрос по поводу вашей регулярки,после обработки регулярки выдает 2 идентичных массива,такое ощущение что в ругулярке идет захват 2 групп

Comment: Если вы используете PHP и preg_match_all(), то должен получаться массив, в первом его ключе должны быть выражения, соответствующие всей регулярке, а в массиве со вторым ключом - "сохраненные", т.е. то, что попало в скобки. 

    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => Manchester Utd</font></font>
                [1] => Frans</font></font>
                [2] => рвот</font></font>
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => Manchester Utd
                [1] => Frans
                [2] => рвот
            )

    )

Answer (score 0):

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Кре
            [1] => Жирный Зомби (5)
            [2] => Бес Гнева (8)
            [3] => Проклятый Оруженосец (4)
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Кре
            [1] => Жирный Зомби (5)
            [2] => Бес Гнева (8)
            [3] => Проклятый Оруженосец (4)
        )

)
```

ВОт такой почему то у меня массив получается

Comment: покажите код

Comment: Если используете PHP, то код должен быть примерно таким:

    preg_match_all('/([^>]+)<\/font><\/font>/', $text, $matches);
    print_r($matches);

Comment: <?php
if(!empty($_POST['url'])){
    $url = $_POST['url'];
    $log = zlib_decode(file_get_contents($url));
    
    $regExpPl = "/([^>]+)<\/font><\/font>/";
    preg_match_all($regExpPl,$log,$matches);
    
    foreach($matches[1] as $key => $player){
        echo $player."</br>";
    }
}
?>

Comment: вероятно, ники в $log повторяются. других причин не вижу

Comment: > int preg_match_all ( string $pattern , string $subject [, array &$matches [, int $flags = PREG_PATTERN_ORDER [, int $offset = 0 ]]] )
...
> flags
> PREG_PATTERN_ORDER
> Упорядочивает результаты так, что элемент $matches[0] содержит массив полных вхождений шаблона, элемент $matches[1] содержит массив вхождений первой подмаски, и так далее.

Видимо браузер просто скрывает закрывающие теги font, а так первый набор отличается именно ими.

Comment: Да скорее всего так и есть

Comment: Ну это мне конечно не мешает,просто хотелось бы знать  из за чего такое!

Comment: Кстати спасибо большое за simple_html_dom, действительно буквально в 2-3 действиях добираешься до нужного элемента.Очень удобно!